# 1000 combobox binding

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, xaml, combobox

I have a WPF form which contains 30x30 grid where each grid cell is a `ComboBox`. ComboBox values and selected value are bound from `DataContext`. The problem is it goes very slow. I have reworked the form so that it displays textboxes instead of comboboxes (and `TextBox` is converted to `ComboBox` on mouse enter) and it work instantly now.

Why are ComboBoxes so slower? Are there any ways to improve massive binding of ComboBoxes?

Comment: Did you use virtualized ComboBoxes? (For an example, see the article [UI Virtualization](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=338)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ComboBox` doesn’t use virtualization(`VirtualizingStackPanel`) by default, you can change the panel used by the control in a very simple way:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

Ref: [Improving Combobox Performance through UI Virtualization](http://blog.kirupa.com/?p=115)

That helps a lot in improving performance in case a `ComboBox` is having thousands of items, not sure how much helpful it will be in your case as having 1000 comboboxes is a lot for UI.

You can also try to put these comboBoxes in a Virtualized panel(like `ListBox` or directly using `VirtualizedStackpanel`).

Another thing you can try is to make your `ComboBox` `ItemSource` bindings asynchronous using [`IsAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync.aspx) property.

I hope you are using `ObservableCollection` as your `ItemSource`;